# How can I validate textboxes that are dependent on each other and display error messages under dynamically (using JS) added input textboxes?

Tags: validation, laravel-8

In my form, I have a "Seminars attended" set of text inputs- User inputs the seminar title, date, and seminar conductor/organizer.

```
                <table class="table" id="addRemoveSeminar">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Title</th>
                            <th scope="col">Date Taken</th>
                            <th scope="col">Conducted By</th>
                            <th><button type="button" name="add" onclick="addSeminar()" id="dynamic-ar-seminar" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add Seminar</button></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row"><input type="text" id="" name="Seminars[0][title]"></th>
                            <td><input type="date" id="" name="Seminars[0][date]"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="" name="Seminars[0][conducted_by]"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

The
form originally loads with just one set of these text inputs, but if user wants to add more seminars, they can click the
"Add Seminar" button, and a new set of these three input boxes will appear. Here is the js code:

JS file:

```
function addSeminar() {
    var i = 0;

        ++i;
        $("#addRemoveSeminar").append('<tr><th scope="row"><input type="text" id="" name="Seminars[' + i +
        '][title]"></th><td><input type="date" id="" name="Seminars[' + i +
        '][date]"></td><td><input type="text" id="" name="Seminars[' + i +
        '][conducted_by]"></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger remove-input-field">Delete</button></td></tr>'
            );

    $(document).on('click', '.remove-input-field', function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });
}
```

As you can see, the name attributes of `title`,`date`, and `conducted_by` will be added as keys to the `Seminars` array.

Question 1:
If validation fails, I don't just want to call a foreach() on all the errors and display them on the top of the page, I want each error to display on the bottom of the textbox it corresponds to.
Even the ones that have been dynamically added through Javascript. How do I do that?

Question 2:
For now, all these inputs are nullable in the validation rule. However, if the user should enter a value on one of the input boxes, I want the other two input boxes to be required.
For example, if a user types in a Seminar title, he can't leave the date and conducted_by input box empty.

I tried reading the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#complex-conditional-validation part, but I'm
struggling to figure out how I can implement the given example

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'games' => 'required|numeric',
]);
```

with my current scenario, since the current validating syntax I use for all of the input is     `request()->validate()`. How can I do this?

My current validation in controller:

```
$validated = request()->validate([
                'Seminars.*.title' => ['nullable','max:100',new LetterSpaceOnly],
            'Seminars.*.date' => ['nullable','before_or_equal: today','date'],
            'Seminars.*.conducted_by' =>  ['nullable','max:100',new LetterSpaceOnly]

]);
```

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

For your second question first, you may use the `required_with` validation rule.
You may check it here in the [documentaion](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-with)

Now, for the second question, since the fields are added after the DOM has been loaded, it's not going to be present when Laravel validates the inputs. 
However, there's a work around here. 
In this example we may use the `old` helper, also you may check it here in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-old) 
A little context here about `old`, when you submit your form, all your inputs will going to be flashed into session, and we can retrieve them using the helper above.
So the workaround here, is whenever tha validation fails, it will return back with the 'old' inputs, using that helper, we can re-create the first table, the user submitted, and we can show errors under each one of the input fields.
For the code now:
This is the code of the view, where we check if we have old values in the session or not:

```php
            <table class="table" id="addRemoveSeminar">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Title</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date Taken</th>
                        <th scope="col">Conducted By</th>
                        <th><button type="button" name="add" onclick="addSeminar()" id="dynamic-ar-seminar" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add Seminar</button></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @if (old('Seminars'))
                        @foreach (old('Seminars') as $key => $seminar)
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <input type="text" id="" name="Seminars[{{ $key }}][title]" value="{{ $seminar['title'] }}">
                                    @if ($errors->has('Seminars.' . $key . '.title'))
                                        {{ $errors->first('Seminars.' . $key . '.title') }}
                                    @endif
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="date" id="" name="Seminars[{{ $key }}][date]" value="{{ $seminar['date'] }}">
                                    @if ($errors->has('Seminars.' . $key . '.date'))
                                        {{ $errors->first('Seminars.' . $key . '.date') }}

                                    @endif
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id="" name="Seminars[{{ $key }}][conducted_by]" value="{{ $seminar['conducted_by'] }}">
                                    @if ($errors->has('Seminars.' . $key . '.conducted_by'))
                                        {{ $errors->first('Seminars.' . $key . '.conducted_by') }}

                                    @endif
                                </td>
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger remove-input-field">Delete</button></td>
                            </tr>

                        @endforeach
                    @else

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">
                                <input type="text" id="" name="Seminars[0][title]">

                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="date" id="" name="Seminars[0][date]">

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="" name="Seminars[0][conducted_by]">

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    @endif
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

and here's the controller validation rules

```php
        $this->validate($request, [
            'Seminars.*.title' => 'sometimes|required_with:Seminars.*.date, Seminars.*.conducted_by',
            'Seminars.*.date' => 'sometimes|required_with:Seminars.*.title, Seminars.*.conducted_by',
            'Seminars.*.conducted_by' => 'sometimes|required_with:Seminars.*.title, Seminars.*.date',
        ]);
...
```

Also, one more thing, in your JS code,  the `onclick` event, should be outside of the function.

```js
function addSeminar() {
     @if (old('Seminars'))
            var i = {{ count(old('Seminars')) }} - 1;
        @else
            i= 0;
        @endif

        ++i;
        $("#addRemoveSeminar").append('<tr><th scope="row"><input type="text" id="" name="Seminars[' + i +
        '][title]"></th><td><input type="date" id="" name="Seminars[' + i +
        '][date]"></td><td><input type="text" id="" name="Seminars[' + i +
        '][conducted_by]"></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger remove-input-field">Delete</button></td></tr>'
            );

    
}

$(document).on('click', '.remove-input-field', function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });
```

For changing the validation messages, you may use it as follows:

```php
 $this->validate($request, [
            'Seminars.*.title' => 'sometimes|required_with:Seminars.*.date, Seminars.*.conducted_by',
            'Seminars.*.date' => 'sometimes|required_with:Seminars.*.title, Seminars.*.conducted_by',
            'Seminars.*.conducted_by' => 'sometimes|required_with:Seminars.*.title, Seminars.*.date',
        ],

    [
        'Seminars.*.title.required_with' => 'Custom message here',
        'Seminars.*.date.required_with' => 'Custom message here',
        'Seminars.*.conducted_by' => 'Custom message here',

    ]);
```

And change the messages as your needs.

I hope everything is clear.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I'm trying this out now. I have a custom rule `LetterSpaceOnly` that I want to include in the validation. How do I do it using the 'rule1|rule2` syntax? When I try to add `new LetterSpaceOnly`, an error is returned
`Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateNewLetterSpaceOnly does not exist.`

Comment: You may use the array version of the validation
`'Seminars.*.title' =>['sometimes',  'required_with:Seminars.*.date, Seminars.*.conducted_by', new LetterSpacing]`

Comment: Function is working, but the errors show up as
`The Seminars.0.date field is required when Seminars.0.title / Seminars.0.conducted_by is present.`. Is there a way to make it more user-readable?

Comment: I edited the answer, check it